# Mocking private method inside a public method

Tags: java, mocking

I've made a test of a `getStudies` method, that has a private method call inside itself. Now, how to mock that call in a test method (see down below)?
It's on a second line in a method for testing `String query = setQueryForChangingState(filterParams);`. I'll provide additional code, if necessary.

**Method for testing**

```
   public Object getStudies(FilterInputModel filterParams) {
        String query = setQueryForChangingState(filterParams);

        logger.info("Get studies query: " + query);

        LinkedMultiValueMap<String, String> queryMap = new LinkedMultiValueMap<>();
        queryMap.add("q", query);

        return Objects.requireNonNull(webClient.post()
                .uri("/query")
                .header(HttpHeaders.AUTHORIZATION, getSessionId())
                .body(BodyInserters.fromMultipartData(queryMap))
                .retrieve()
                .bodyToMono(QueryResponse.class)
                .block())
                .data;
    }
```

**Private method**

```
private String setQueryForChangingState(FilterInputModel filterParams) {
    String query = "SELECT id, " +
            "basf_study_id__cr.name__v, " +
            "name__v, " +
            "state__v, " +
            "bas_core__cr.name__v, " +
            "object_type__vr.name__v, " +
            "external__c, " +
            "contract_laboratory__cr.name__v, " +
            "object_type__v " +
            "FROM study__c " +
            "WHERE object_type__vr.name__v = 'External Study' " +
            "AND contract_laboratory__c != null " +
            "AND state__v = 'study_setup_completed_state__c'";
if (!filterParams.getCores().isEmpty()) {
    query = query + " AND bas_core__c CONTAINS('" + String.join("','", filterParams.getCores()) + "')";
}
if (!filterParams.getStudyStartDate().isEmpty()) {
    if (filterParams.getStudyStartDate().size() == 1) {
        query = query + " AND study_start_date__c = '" + filterParams.getStudyStartDate().get(0) + "'";
    } else if (filterParams.getStudyStartDate().size() == 2) {
        query = query + " AND study_start_date__c BETWEEN '" + filterParams.getStudyStartDate().get(0) + "' AND '" + filterParams.getStudyStartDate().get(1) + "'";
    } else {
        logger.info("Date range has to many inputs!");
    }
}
return query;
}
```

**My test**

```
@Test
@DisplayName("Test getStudies")
void getStudies() throws IOException {
    Path filePath = Path.of("src/test/resources/__files/jsonFile.json");
    String body = Files.read(filePath.toFile(), Charset.defaultCharset());

wireMockServer.stubFor(post(urlEqualTo("/api/v16.1/query"))
        .willReturn(aResponse()
                .withStatus(200)
                .withHeader("Content-Type", "application/json")
                .withBody(body))
);
List<String> cores = List.of("core");
List<String> dates = List.of("startDate");
List<String> objectTypes = List.of("objectType");
        inputModel = new FilterInputModel(cores,dates, "state",objectTypes,
        "area","analytMethod", "wp", "subDesc", "analytMonitor", "ecoMonitor",
        "subType", "analytNeeded", "8e6a2", "methodAvailable",
        "analytPhase", "subAvailable","subShipped", "external",
        "uploadValidator","contractLab");

Object response = vaultServiceTest.getStudies(inputModel);
QueryResponse jsonBody = new ObjectMapper().readValue(body, QueryResponse.class);
assertEquals(response, jsonBody.data);
```

I guess it could be done, but I'm not sure how.

Comment: why not turn that private method in a service (call) and mock that?

Comment: Actually, I just need to mock 'String query = setQueryForChangingState(filterParams);' inside the 'getStudies' method, but I'm not sure how. I'm totally new to mocking.

Comment: yes, I know. But not all mocking frameworks support mocking of private methods, and those that do, tend to warn to be cautious. https://www.baeldung.com/powermock-private-method

Comment: Is it really necessary to mock the private method? It seems like it would be enough  to mock the call to the web service. The private method is part of the implementation of the class under test, so don't you want to test that, too? What happens if you don't mock it and run the test as is?

Comment: @TimMoore >> The test passes without the mocking of the ´String query = setQueryForChangingState(filterParams);´. But it is required to test it nevertheless. I just don't know how to insert it into my test.

Comment: This seems like an integration test of some sort, so I'd rather suggest to actually test this method (indirectly) instead of mocking it; otherwise what's the point of this test? You simply make up several different payloads and then verify what's actually sent to the server each time:  `wireMockServer.verify(1, postRequestedFor(urlEqualTo("/api/v16.1/query")).withRequestBody(new EqualToPattern(<whatever is expected>)));`

Comment: Of course you can set its visibility to package-private, put the @Spy on `vaultServiceTest` and then mock the return value inside the test with `doReturn("FAKE").when(vaultServiceTest).setQueryForChangingState(any());` but that's not really a good practice